# List of possible rooms instead of possible directions

Tags: inform7

I try to list possible directions to which the user might go. But for the tone of the story it would be nicer not to say "you can go north and south" but "you can go to the bathroom and the kitchen".

I found hat code but it only shows the directions.

```
Definition: a direction (called thataway) is viable if the room 
thataway from the location is a room.

After looking:
    say "you can go [list of viable directions]."
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not the nicest way of doing it, but I had a similar problem and I ended up iterating over the list of directions you created and added each of the rooms to a list of rooms, one could then say:

```
nLooking is a number that varies. nLooking is 0.

After looking:
    now nLooking is 1;
    let accessibleRooms be a list of rooms;
    let pDirections be list of viable directions;
    repeat with dirToLookAt running through pDirections:
        try silently going dirToLookAt;
        if rule succeeded:
            add the location of the player to accessibleRooms;
            try silently going the opposite of dirToLookAt;
    now nLooking is 0;
    say "You can go to [accessibleRooms].".

Before going through a locked door when nLooking is 1:
    stop the action.
```

I used nLooking to block the output

> (first opening door)
>   It seems to be locked.

when looking for the rooms one could access.
`if rule succeeded` checks if the palyer was able to go to the room. If that is the case the room the player walked in is added to the list and the player is moved back to where he came from.

This works only if one does not make a chaotic map where moving in the opposite direction of where one came from does not mean one lands in the same room. One could possibly just place the player back in the room he came from...

Late answer I know but maybe it helps people with the same problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test it in my next game. I solved it in another way by mentioning doors that lead to other rooms. Not that nice but it could be used in a more artsy way ;)